# Onesignal notification issue Mismatched Bundle ID (Sandbox) in OneSignal

Tags: ios, swift, onesignal

I made an ios app and I added onesignal to my app, I tested my app from my phone it works well but I uploaded my app to appstore, notifications not work. onesignal gives me this issue "Mismatched Bundle ID (Sandbox) in OneSignal"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a push certificate, you'll be provided with two .p12 files (mostly)
One for Sandboxing (internal testing inside the company or debug testing) and one for Release.
Probably you haven't uploaded the Release version to the one-signal panel.

Comment: How Can I upload certificate for release version, I don't know

Comment: I don't have access to the One-Signal panel for my previous company anymore, But i'm pretty sure it was under App settings > Push notification settings or something like that.